# Why s is returning 0 when inputs are 2,3,4?

Tags: c, floating-point, return

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
  int a,b,c;
  float s,area;

  printf("Enter 3 sides of triangle:");
  scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

  s=(a+b+c)/2;
  printf("%d",s);

  area=sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
  printf("Area of triangle is : %.1f",area);
}
```

and also explain bitwise complement operator why ~0 is -1? How it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing integer division, try this

```
s=((float)(a+b+c)) / 2.0;
```

if you don't cast the numbers

```
s = (2 + 4 + 3) / 2 -> 9 / 2 - > 4
```

then

```
area=sqrt(4*(4-2)*(4-3)*(4-4));
                      /*  ^ this is 0
```

and hence

```
area=sqrt(4*2*1*0) -> sqrt(0) -> 0;
```

As other answers already mention, the `~` bitwise operator flips the bits of it's operand meaning that if you have the number 10 it's binary representation is

```
00001010
^^^^^^^^   
11110101
```

and if you apply the `~` operator on it, it becomes

```
11110101 -> 245 // unsigned
```

which becomes `245 - 256 = -11`, see [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: what,s the problem if i am doing integer division??? i am storing the result in float.i didn't understand the concept..can u please explain thi??

Comment: ohk thankzzz... i got it now..can you also explain bitwise complement operator???

Comment: The cast isn't needed there.

Answer (score 0):

> why s is returning 0 when inputs are 2,3,4?

Because you're doing `int` calculations.

> and also explain bitwise complement oprator why ~0 is -1??how it works????

Assuming 8-bit, 0 is:

```
00000000
```

What is ~0?

```
11111111
```

In Two's complement it's -1, because if you flip all bits and add 1 to the result, you'll get:

```
00000001
```

and since the MSB is 1, the result is negative.

Comment: Two's complement is a representation system for numbers, some do store in this form, some doesn't.

Comment: sorry.. but i didn;t get it.